# Update Statement sets value to null instead of primary key

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am developing a web application that will allow you to assign a rider to a van via a form. 
You click on the rider in the table on the page, a pop up occurs, you select the van and then click add. The issue I am having is my update statement is setting all values in my mysql table to null instead of the primary key from another table.

```
 <div class="table-responsive" id="refresh">
                                    <table id="mainTable" class="table m-b-0 table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Primary Key</th>
                                                <th>Party Name</th>
                                                <th>Address</th>
                                                <th>Number in Party</th>
                                                <th>Number of Coolers</th>
                                                <th>Phone Number</th>
                                                <th>Time of PickUP</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <?php while($row = $q->fetch()):?>
                                            <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#selectVan">
                                                <td id="riderName" name="primKey">
                                                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['P_Key']) ?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td id="riderName" name="riderName">
                                                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['partyNM']) ?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['address1'])?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['numParty'])?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['numCooler'])?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['phoneNum'])?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['pickUp'])?>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php endwhile; $sql=null;?>
                                        </tbody>
                                        <tfoot>
                                        </tfoot>
                                    </table>
                                    <!--Select a van for rider-->
                                    <div id="selectVan" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                                        aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select Van</h4>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-danger m-b-5"
                                                        type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                <?php
                                                    $sql = 'Select P_Key, nameVan from vanInfo where in_active=0';
                                                    $q = $dbh->query($sql);
                                                    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                                ?>
                                                    <form method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal"
                                                        data-parsley-validate novalidate>
                                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                                            <select class="form-control select2" id="selectedVan" name="selectedVan">
                                                                <option>Available Vans</option>
                                                                <?php while($row = $q->fetch()):?>
                                                                    <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['nameVan']) ?>">
                                                                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['nameVan']) ?>
                                                                    </option>
                                                                <?php endwhile;?>
                                                                </optgroup>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group row">

                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect m-b-5"
                                                                data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                            <button name="addRiderToVan" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light m-b-5">Add</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <?php
                                                            if(isset($_POST["addRiderToVan"])){
                                                            try {
                                                            $riderKey = $_POST["primKey"];
                                                            $vanName = $_POST["selectedVan"];
                                                            $sql = "UPDATE riderInfo set van_key=(select P_Key from vanInfo where 
                                                            nameVan = '$vanName' and in_active = '0') where P_Key = $riderKey";
                                                            $dbh->exec($sql);
                                                            }catch(Exception $e){
                                                            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                                                            }
                                                            }
                                                            $sql = null;
                                                        ?>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                </div>
```

I need to update the riderInfo van_key column the P_Key of my vanInfo table for the selected van.

Comment: **Warning:** You are _wide open_ to [SQL-injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Use [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of injection unescaped userdata directly into your queries.

Comment: Also, you're defining `$riderName = $_POST["riderName"]` while trying to use `$riderKey` in your query? As far as I can see, there are no `$riderKey`-variable defined.

Comment: Why don't you debug the SQL statement isolated? This could help you to see whether the statement is already built in an unexpected way or the statement, build as you expect it, performs some unexpected updates

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a lot of things here.

First edit your select query introducing the primary key.

Second i suggest you to name the select HTML item instead the option contained in it.
Like:

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="selectedVan" >
```

Third, the option will be like this:

```
<option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['idVan']) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['nameVan']) ?></option>
```

finally, get the $_POST["selectedVan"] (select above) and update the database

```
$sql = "UPDATE riderInfo set van_key=$vanKey where P_Key = $riderKey";
```

Comment: That worked in updating my field however, it didn't limit it to only the one person. Instead it updated all records to that van P_Key

Comment: @Connerdy - If you want to update just one, you should define more `WHERE`-rules. The database doesn't know what you want. It only does what you tell it to do.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I did. 
$sql = "UPDATE riderInfo set van_key=(select P_Key from vanInfo where 
nameVan = '$vanName' and in_active = '0') where P_Key = $riderKey"

Comment: I've also added the rest of the code for this snippet.

Comment: @Connerdy - That query still only have one single `WHERE`-criteria for the update: `where P_Key = $riderKey`. It doesn't matter if you add more criteria's inside the sub-query (the select), that only affects what you set the value to, not which records that will be updated.

Comment: I understand that. The P_Key is a unique value and therefore only ties it to one record. Looking at the rest of my code above, what do you suggest where I define the $riderKey?

Comment: @Connerdy - I suggest that you start by rewriting your queries using prepared statements. When that's done, test your queries on their own to see if they work. If they do, put them all together. No point of trying to fix bugs in highly insecure code which you need to rewrite anyway. It's also easier for us (and you) if you strip away all extra code (like all the HTML and other queries etc) when you test your queries.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson For this particular issue there is no way for the user to input information? How can SQL injection occur if the user can't input their own text?

Comment: @Connerdy - _"the user can't input their own text"_ - Where do you think the data in the `$_POST`-array comes from? Anyone can pass what ever they want to your file and your code gladly use it to manually build the query without any validation or escaping. They can either do their own post (cURL, postman or some other way) or just right click on the select-box and choose "inspect element" and modify all the values using the browsers developer tools. The point is, _never_ trust data that comes from the client (browser/form/url or where ever). Always assume that the data is malicious.